# Correct way to handle a NULL ppPins parameter in DirectShow Filter's EnumPins method (Delphi/DSPACK)?

Tags: delphi, filter, directshow, dspack

I have a custom push source filter written in Delphi 6 using the DSPACK DirectShow component library on a Windows XP/32 machine.  During coding I ran into a problem with **range check errors** occurring in the **BaseClass** unit belonging to DSPACK (BaseClass.pas), after I turned on *Range Checking* in my application's Compiler options.

The error is occurring during my the EnumPins() method.  Note, this method resides in DSPACK's BaseClass unit, not my application.  I traced the problem and discovered it occurs when the Filter graph I build that uses my filter, plays the filter.  Note, my filter is being directly incorporated into my application as a private unregistered filter not as an external AX.  When DirectShow calls into the base class method **TBCEnumPins.Next()**, if the **ppPins** parameter is **NIL** then the range check error occurs.  Since I am not a DirectShow expert, I am not sure what is the correct way to fix this error without disturbing the proper flow of the DirectShow pin enumeration process.  If instead it is a true error condition that is not to be ignored, then I need to know what is the correct Exception to throw or HRESULT code to return in this event.  Can anyone tell me the proper way to adjust this code for a NIL ppPins parameter?  The full method code is below with the line at which the range check error occurs, highlighted:

```
function TBCEnumPins.Next(cPins: ULONG; out ppPins: IPin; pcFetched: PULONG): HRESULT;
type
  TPointerDynArray = array of Pointer;
  TIPinDynArray = array of IPin;
var
  Fetched: cardinal;
  RealPins: integer;
  Pin: TBCBasePin;
begin
    // ATI: Debugging range check error.
    try
        if pcFetched <> nil then
          pcFetched^ := 0
        else
          if (cPins>1) then
          begin
            result := E_INVALIDARG;
            exit;
          end;
        Fetched := 0; // increment as we get each one.

        // Check we are still in sync with the filter
        // If we are out of sync, we should refresh the enumerator.
        // This will reset the position and update the other members, but
        // will not clear cache of pins we have already returned.
        if AreWeOutOfSync then
          Refresh;

        // Calculate the number of available pins
        RealPins := min(FPinCount - FPosition, cPins);
        if RealPins = 0 then
        begin
          result := S_FALSE;
          exit;
        end;

        {  Return each pin interface NOTE GetPin returns CBasePin * not addrefed
           so we must QI for the IPin (which increments its reference count)
           If while we are retrieving a pin from the filter an error occurs we
           assume that our internal state is stale with respect to the filter
           (for example someone has deleted a pin) so we
           return VFW_E_ENUM_OUT_OF_SYNC }

        while RealPins > 0 do
        begin
          // Get the next pin object from the filter */
          inc(FPosition);
          Pin := FFilter.GetPin(FPosition-1);
          if Pin = nil then
          begin
            // If this happend, and it's not the first time through, then we've got a problem,
            // since we should really go back and release the iPins, which we have previously
            // AddRef'ed.
            ASSERT(Fetched = 0);
            result := VFW_E_ENUM_OUT_OF_SYNC;
            exit;
          end;

          // We only want to return this pin, if it is not in our cache
          if FPinCache.IndexOf(Pin) = -1 then
          begin
            // From the object get an IPin interface
            TPointerDynArray(@ppPins)[Fetched] := nil; // <<<<<< THIS IS WHERE THE RANGE CHECK ERROR OCCURS.
            TIPinDynArray(@ppPins)[Fetched] := Pin;
            inc(Fetched);
            FPinCache.Add(Pin);
            dec(RealPins);
          end;
        end; // while RealPins > 0 do

        if (pcFetched <> nil) then pcFetched^ := Fetched;

        if (cPins = Fetched) then result := NOERROR else result := S_FALSE;
    except
        On E: Exception do
        begin
            OutputDebugString(PChar(
                '(TBCEnumPins.Next) Exception class name(' + E.ClassName + ') message: ' + E.Message
            ));

            raise;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

**UPDATE:** It appears that the DSPACK code is sound from a technical standpoint, but a little odd from a coding idiom viewpoint and is structured in a way that is not compatible with range checking.  The NIL coming in via the ppPins "out" parameter maps to the destination buffer the caller passes to TBCEnumPins.Next() as the ppPins parameter.  For example, the code below comes from this page:

http://tanvon.wordpress.com/2008/09/07/enumerating-the-directshow-filter-pin/

On that page is the following code that interacts with a DirectShow Filter to enumerate the Filter's pins:

```
IEnumPins * pEP;
pSF->EnumPins(&pEP);
IPin * pOutPin;
while(pEP->Next(1,&pOutPin,0) == S_OK)
{
    PIN_DIRECTION pDir;
    pOutPin->QueryDirection(&pDir);
    if(pDir == PINDIR_OUTPUT)
        break;// success
    pOutPin->Release();
}
pEP->Release();
```

By telling the Next() method how many pins to retrieve, the TBCEnumPins.Next() method code with its unusual Dynamic array cast works out to be safe since it will only copy into the ppPins "out" parameter as many as pins as were requested in the Next() functions "cPins" parameter.  As long as the caller passes a destination buffer that can hold the number of pins requested in "cPins" everything works fine (as long as range checking is turned off).  Note, in this case, the IPin variable named "outPin" is the destination buffer.  The range check error occurs if range checking is turned on because Delphi treats the NIL as a zero length array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspicious of your declaration of the `ppPins` parameter and your casts to `TPointerDynArray` and `TIPinDynArray`.

You will get range errors if you pretend that the array passed in is a Delphi dynamic array when in fact it is not. Delphi dynamic arrays have a block of memory that precedes the first item of the array and identifies the reference count to the array, and it's length. Since this block is missing in your array, tricking the compiler into believing it is there will result in the error you see.

I'd do it as shown below. This matches the declarations used in MSDN. You have to use a bit of pointer arithmetic but I believe it is easier to do this since your code now will be easy to relate to any C++ samples you can find online.

```
type
  PIPin = ^IPin;

function TBCEnumPins.Next(cPins: ULONG; ppPins: PIPin; pcFetched: PULONG): HRESULT;
begin
  ... 
  // this is the meat of the loop, assign to the output array, and increment
  Pointer(ppPins)^ := nil; // initialise the intf ref to avoid bogus _Release
  ppPins^ := Pin;
  inc(ppPins);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Hello @David Heffeman.  I'd explain the code but as I said, that's the stock code that came with DSPACK so I don't know the reasoning behind it's structure.  Note the "range check error" is a known error on the DSPACK (progdigy) forums.  I'll give your code a try.

Comment: @Robert I added one line of code. I realised I missed the fact that the array needs to be zero initialised to avoid Delphi writing in calls to _Release on uninitialised references. To be honest that's probably easiest with a call to FillChar or ZeroMemory outside the loop.

Comment: Heffeman.  Please see my comment to Roman in his reply, about the "out" parameter/NIL combination.

Comment: @Robert `ppPins`  should never be `NULL`. And I mean `ppPins` as per MSDN, not in your code. It would be so much easier if you answered my question about what really is `NULL`. Anyway, it's clear that your original code is wrong when range checking is on. I do believe that my answer explains everything you have repored.

Comment: Heffeman.  As I said, it isn't my code.  It's part of the DSPACK BaseClass unit. ppPins can be NIL if that's what happens to be in the destination buffer when the caller calls TBCEnumPins.Next().  If it is NIL then when range checking is on, it is treated as a zero length array.  The NIL is just what happens to be at the start of the destination buffer pointed to by ppPins.  By taking the address of an "out" (by reference) parameter, the original author in essence is pointing to the start of the destination buffer that will receive the fetched pin.  See my "update" to my original post.

Comment: Your update still misses the point somewhat I think. In the delphi code you posted, @ppPins is never nil. The contents of ppPins may be nil but that's irrelevant. Anyway, I do think we have pretty much cornered this one now.

Comment: Heffeman.  I'll look again tomorrow and see if I can improve the update.  I'm without sleep at the moment (early AM here now) and bleary-eyed.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

[`IEnumPins::Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd376612%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method is not supposed to be called with `ppPins == NULL`. The best way to handle is thus return immediately with `E_POINTER` error code.

You might want to check caller's code to find out why you have `NULL` there in first place.

Comment: I actually doubt that ppPins really is NULL. If it was then there would be access violation rather than range error. It's also complicated by the fact that the COM declaration of `ppPins` is a pointer to an `IPin` but the code in the question uses an `out` parameter in a dubious way.

Comment: Agree. Talking about range checking, it looks like the problem might come up if caller requests 2+ pins to be enum'med at once, and the function is defined in a way that `ppPins` is a single value, not an array. Still, OP asked about `NULL` argument and here we go. I supposed that calling code is not external, and OP might be having a problem on caller side within his own code.

Comment: @David Heffernan.  Are you sure an A/V would necessarily be fired here?  Delphi treats NIL array as zero length and if the compiler treated it as such first, a range check error would be fired before an access violation when the index is applied to the empty array since it is zero length.

Comment: @RobertOschler Yes you are correct. My mistake. But you must take my point about this misuse of dynamic arrays. Perhaps the sample code you copied works with range checking off.

Comment: @Roman R.  Re: "caller".  That's what concerns me, that somehow I did not set up my pins correctly, and that is propagating to the Next() function with ppPins ending up as NIL.  It's difficult to debug because DSPACK's MediaControl.Run() command fires off a CMD_RUN command verb to the Filter's thread.  The only thing I am seeing on the stack above TBCEnumPins.Next() is MediaControl.Run().  I guess that the actual caller is the Filter's thread calling back into the main thread where the Next() method executes.  The other two threads I see are stopped in an "Unknown" state.

Comment: @David Hefferman.  Re: range checking off.  Yes that's what everyone else does.

Comment: @RobertOschler Could you clear up what is `nil`. Does `ppPins` in your code evaluate to `nil`, or is it `@ppPins` that is `nil`? The latter is what should not happen and that it an error committed by the caller. The former is perfectly natural. There is confusion because your definition of `ppPins` does not match that in MSDN.

Comment: To David and Roman, ignore the comment about the Filter's thread calling back into the main thread.  If that was the case, I'd see the code executing in that thread's context, instead of the main thread's context.  Could it be a DirectShow or O/S process/thread calling back into me?

Comment: @Robert: you can receive pin enumeration calls on any thread. Typically, you have them on "main" thread where you construct the graph, but nothing prevents from enumerating on worker threads such as if filter are looking for pins or connections, or simply tracing topology, or an external tool such as `GraphEdit` is doing so.

Comment: @Roman R. Yes.  The TBCEnumPins.Next() code is the complement to code like this: http://tanvon.wordpress.com/2008/09/07/enumerating-the-directshow-filter-pin/ The reason the odd "out" parameter/NIL combination works, is because the caller is responsible for telling the Next() method how many pins to fetch and to allocate enough space for the Dest buffer and then pass a pointer to the start of that buffer.  In the linked web page, that corresponds to a single IPin object named outPin.  So the code is correct from a technical standpoint, but odd from an idiom and range checking point of view.

Comment: In the code snippet behind the link above `ppPins` would never be `NULL`, it is always a valid pointer.

Comment: @Roman R.  Yes.  The NIL is not the "IPin outPin" variable address because as you said that would be a valid address.  The NIL is the current *value* for "outPin".  Since the DSPACK BaseClass author is taking the address of an "out" parameter (@ppPins), the assignment copies the Pin being fetched into the area pointed to by outPin, it's value.  Please see my update to my original post.